# Adobe Flash start animation

Tags: animation, actionscript-2, flash-cs5, symbols

I have some symbols in my flash project. It's a chemistry elements. It's pathes looks like

```
Scene 1->elem h
Scene 1->elem he 
Scene 1->elem li
```

When i click one of this elements its play their animation - element zoom in. When i clicked on zoomed element - its zoom out. I need if i zoom in the element, all another elements zoom out (if their zoomed ofcourse).

The question is how to start symbol animation from another symbol.

I use Adobe Flash Professional CS5.5 and action-script 2

Comment: How does your code look like ?

Comment: Only on (release) {gotoAndPlay("zoomout");} but it is inside one symbol. I need to do this from another symbol.

Comment: I solve this. It must be this._parent.<name_of_btn>.gotoAndPlay("ZoomOut")

Answer (score 0):

On the main timeline, you want to create 2 functions:

```
function resetAllClips()
{
   // Some loop/code to reset all clips
}

function zoomClip(clip)
{
   // Reset Everything
   resetAllClips();

   // Now Zoom in
   // ... your code for zooming ...
}
```

Now you attach an click handler on each of your clips and call zoomClip(clipinstance);
All your code can reside on the main timeline.